# How to cache updated data offline with Cloud Firestore of Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like that any data modification by an user without internet connection is cached and uploaded to CloudFirestore Firebase when he get internet connection back.
Here my code which should save data updates:

```
mSaveProfileUpdatesImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
                    User user = transaction.get(docRef).toObject(User.class);
                    if (mUsernameTextInputLayout.getEditText() != null)
                        user.setUsername(mUsernameTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
                    if (mEmailTextInputLayout.getEditText() != null)
                        user.setEmail(mEmailTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
                    if (mPhoneTextInputLayout.getEditText() != null)
                        user.setPhone(mPhoneTextInputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
                    if (mAddressTextInputLayout != null && user.getTempAddress() != null)
                    transaction.set(docRef, user);
                    return null;
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Failed to save updates",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

When internet connection is missing, the Snackbar is showed, but when connection is activated and so ready to update data, Snackbar is always showed.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your application class in OnCreate() method.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I'm using Cloud Firestore and not Reatime Firebase. Adding something similar to it, however doesn't work

Comment: @FedericoRizzo try with this,                          FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

Comment: I had already added this. The transactions are the problem. They don't support offline updates

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are not supported for offline use - they can't be cached or saved for later.  This is because a transaction absolutely requires round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So what is the correct way for offline updates? What should i use?

Comment: There is no correct way to perform transaction updates offline.  It's not supported.  You can do non-transaction updates only offline.

Comment: Ok i understand. So what is the alternative to transactions in this case?

Comment: So maybe a snapshot could be the solution